# MySQL ENUM issue for month input

Tags: mysql, enums

I would like to create a table which restrict the input for Month while fail to load the csv file.

The `.mysql`script i employed is following

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Hactl;
CREATE TABLE  Hactl.table1(
    Type ENUM('M','C') NOT NULL,
    Region VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    City VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Imp DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    Exp DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    TS DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    Year INT(4) NOT NULL,
    Month ENUM('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar',
           'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
           'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep',
           'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec') NOT NULL
    /*UNIQUE(Type, Region, Country, City, Year, Month)*/
)
COLLATE = 'latin1_general_cs'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then i would like to load csv file to the table by

```
USE Hactl;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/LI Ho Yin/Google Drive/GA Project/Cargo/Cargo.Statistics/data/Hactl/201207Hac.csv'
INTO TABLE table1
FIELdS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

While there is problem to load month attribute it is empty for whole column, while i success to load the month attribute if i use `Month char(3) NOT NULL` in `CREATER TABLE` instead.

[image]

And the .csv file i have is

[image]

Comment: Can you show the month column?

Comment: hi @yossico, that is successful case using char(3). It is blank for using enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a mistake to think that an ENUM is text. Looks like You are trying to input text into an ENUM column, mysql would expect a number for that.

I would suggest you import into a temporary table with the textual column first then copy it to your working table and use a CASE to change the textual month into an ENUM.

Comment: hi @Giles, can i restrict it to text for ENUM? and thats mean it is act as factor that Jan is 1, Feb is 2 etc.

Comment: Plus i do not understand why column Type that i can load successfully? which is text too.

Comment: No, the ENUM is stored as a number, it is only when you do a select from it that mysql looks up the textual values. As I said you will need to do some post-processing on the text you are importing, this is not unusual practice when importing flat data files.

Comment: Actually you could use the SET clause to do this in the LOAD DATA statement (I normally post process, but this should work too). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html. No idea why the type column works, are you sure you get both M and C?

Comment: sorry that i m new to mysql and not reli sure the set statement. i shd type like set month character='latin1_general_cs'?

Comment: Sorry, not too familiar with the SET in LOAD DATA INFILE myself and would not want to give bad examples. That link has some examples about half way down.